# Get access to MediaElement custom source

Tags: silverlight, mediaelement

I am currently using the MediaElement with a custom source that is derived from MediaStreamSource. Is there anyway I can gain access to this object from the MediaElement? There is a Source member but it is just a URI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an update

The only way I found to do this was to just keep the source around. This way you can get to it later.